# How to speed up of selecting data from a big array

Tags: python, numpy, random

--Hi, all

I have a big numpy array (named "Original_data") with the size of (512,512,600,51). I want to do boot strapping with the following codes

```
N_total_sig = 600
rand_Select_sig = np.random.randint(N_total_sig, size = N_total_sig)
sig = Origianl_data[:,:,rand_Select_sig,:];
```

But it is very slow with the above codes. Would you please tell me if there is a method to speed up of selecting data from a big array?

Thanks
Erick

Comment: looks like you are copying the whole array, while shuffling (sort of) the 600 size dimension.  What's the speed of this operation compared the a simple copy?

Comment: do you realize you could get repeats in that index?

Comment: Yes, I will get repeats in that index.

Comment: It might be faster to sort rand_Select_sig first, as that will give you the most cache-efficient behavior. That would have the downside that Origianl_data would have random data, but not in a random order. I don't know if you care about that.

Comment: The input array seems really HUGE : 30 GiB for 32-bit items and 60 GiB for 64-bit ones (default). Copying 60 GiB of data in RAM is fundamentally slow. Creating a new array of 60 GiB is even slower due to page faults. There is no way to make this very fast (at least clearly not in Numpy). The key is not to do such a big copy. Page faults can be avoided by preallocating the array and reuse it. What means "very slow" to you : how long does it takes and on what hardware? What is the type of the array items?

Comment: Thank you! all. I need to repeat this boot strapping 100 times. I will take me about 20 hours to finish one experimental condition. But I have 3(condition 1)*6(condition 2)*5(condition 3), which means I need 1800 hours to finish all the conditions. @ Nick ODell, I will try your suggestion to sort rand_Select_sig first. I only care about the average of the 600 samples to get the mean with dimension of  (512,512, 51).

Comment: If you only want to compute the mean, then there is no need to actually create the array (which require to read dozens of GiB, to then write the same amount and then read it again). You can compute the mean on the fly. This should be at least 3 times faster (probably even 5x due to page faults). This is the kind of information which is critical for performance...

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to read all images to create the mean images instead of create a big array. But it is even slower because I need to read a large amount of images for each condition. Using sort rand_Select_sig dosen't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct solution to my problem, but there is an alternate way.

According to the suggestions by  Jérôme Richard and Jérôme Richard, I try to avoid Copy 60 GiB of data in RAM. I did the following things.

1. Bootstraping to get the index of files.
2. load these files and calculate the mean on the fly.

By using the above strategy, the speed is still not fast. But the good thing is that I can run my codes in multiple workstations (These workstations don't have big RAM.)